# Decrease points with respect to NSTimer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer

How to decrease points every seconds (for eg. Question 1: having 10 points) with respect to NSTimer ?
I have decrease to this points till 15 seconds only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yep, m trying. Actually i don't know how to save every seconds of NSTimer in particular variable

Comment: Then create a timer that calls a method once per second. Have that method decrement your score by 1 (and presumably, if the time is now zero, stop that timer).

Comment: it means you want to save each decrease second store or what..?

Comment: @Rob i m already created that method

Comment: @Nitin, yes u r right. i have to save that decrease point. actually i m takig 1 countdown. Countdown goes from 15 to 0. But problem is the point decrease only @ inital point i.e Countdown goes from 15 to 14 at that time point decrease after that it become stable.

Comment: You should share your code for both creating (and launching the timer, as well as the salient details of the method that decrements the score.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your interface

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSTimer *timer;
    int seconds;
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

And this in your implementation where you need it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    seconds = 1;    
}

- (void)timerTick:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%d",seconds);
    if (seconds == 15) {
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
    seconds++;
}
```